# How to visualize a frame pose as a path

Tags: slam, navigation, pose, rviz, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to generate an image similar to the one at the end of the demo video here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping

In the image, the generated map and the pose of the /base_link frame over time in the /map frame are overlayed. What is the best way to build such an image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28069/how-to-visualize-a-frame-pose-as-a-path/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map in the video was generated using the [hector_geotiff](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_geotiff) node. This node retrieves the map and trajectory via services as stated at the wiki page. The trajectory is tracked via the [hector_trajector_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_trajectory_server) package, which provides a node that saves a tf based trajectory given a source and target frame. The trajectory is published on a topic as well as available as a service.

Have you looked at the ['Mapping using logged data'](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData) tutorial? The process of mapping and saving to geotiff is described there. Note that the map saving functionality works with maps generated by gmapping or other SLAM systems as well.

/edit: This example launch file should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
  
  <node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
    <param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
    <param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="/base_link" />
    <param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="4" />
    <param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="0.25" />
  </node>


  <node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
    <remap from="map" to="/dynamic_map" />
    <param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps" />
    <param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="hector_slam_map" />
    <param name="draw_background_checkerboard" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="draw_free_space_grid" type="bool" value="true" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

The geotiff map image will be saved every time you publish on the syscommand topic like this:

```
rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-02-21**:
Thanks, I did see that but I didn't realize it would work with gmapping (which I'm using currently). I assume the saved map includes the trajectory overlay?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-02-21**:
Yes it does by default. See edited post above, this launch file should work out of the box if I haven't overlooked anything.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-02-21**:
Beautiful! Works great, thanks!

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-08-03**:
https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/tree/noetic-devel/hector_trajectory_server is the localtion of the source code.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Rviz, if you enable a `nav_msgs/Odometry` topic corresponding to `/base_link`, it will display `/base_link`'s positions over time. You can manually set the number of messages to store in Rviz and then you can see progress over time.

[image]

https://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Odometry

This, of course, assumes that you are correctly publishing an odometry message. This can also be done with a `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` that is published based on your robot's position.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [jsk_rviz_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/jsk_rviz_plugins?distro=indigo) (that is available via apt for some ROS distros), there is [TFTrajectory](http://jsk-visualization.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jsk_rviz_plugins/plugins/tf_trajectory.html) plugin (, which I assume relies only on tf data over the time, but I haven't looked into detail).
[image: image description] (img from https://jsk-visualization.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/tf_trajectory.png)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---